# Equivalent of `nice` for filesystem IO?

Tags: backup, rsync, nice

When I'm running an `rsync` backup job which involves copying over large files, the machine running the backup (both Mac desktops and Linux servers) grinds to a halt and the load average goes through the roof.

I've tried:

- `nice`ing the `rsync` process (doesn't help - the bottleneck is the disk)
- On Linux, `renice`ing a `kjournald` (helps, but seems like a hack and doesn't work on the Mac)
- Using the `--bwlimit` `rsync` flag (helps, but it means all the transfers are slow - even when they don't need to be)

So, is there any way I can "`nice`" `rsync`'s IO so the machines are useable while the backup is running?

PS: I'm aware of the dangers of `rsync` on the Mac… But I've used [BackupBouncer](http://github.com/n8gray/Backup-Bouncer) to verify my backups, though, and they seem OK.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the `setpriority` API on Mac OS X is supposed to be able to alter IO scheduling (see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setpriority.2.html). I don't have any MacOS handy so I can't test that `nice` actually changes the IO priority.

On the Linux side, `ionice` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Here's what the `setpriority` manpage says: "When setting a thread into background state the scheduling priority is set to lowest value, disk and network IO are throttled." -- which seems to indicate that disk/network IO are only throttled when something is niced down to 20 (the "background state").

Comment: Some quick testing also seems to confirm this - when the backup script was only niced to 10 (ie, `nice backup`), I noticed a slowdown... But when it's niced down to 20 (ie, `nice -n 20 backup`), I don't notice any slowdown.

Comment: (and by "noticed a slowdown" I mean "noticed that interactive programs running on the computer didn't respond as quickly as they normally do")

Comment: It's a little disappointing that you only get throttling at a priority of 20, though.

Comment: +1, Nice answer.  Always wondered about twiddling IO.

Comment: The background state is only set when you do a setpriority with PRIO_DARWIN_BG (0x1000), which you cannot set with the CLI nice.

Comment: Is there one for network IO? Or does this work for network IO aswell?

Comment: `renice -n 20 -p PID` doesn't seem to result in much better performance for me, as in... if I SIGSTOP the process using disk IO my other requests are *much* faster.

Answer (score 4):

On linux you can use `ionice` http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice

Comment: Example usage: `ionice -c idle rsync ...args...`